# Trick_winner Funciton

Tags: python

I have created a class function called trick_winner(self) within the class Cards which take the value within self.trick1 for example self.trick1 = ('AH' 'JH' 'KH' '2H') and returns the pairs in order from great to least, being that 'A' is the highest value followed by '7', 'J', 'K', 'Q', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2'. But when I use the built in sort function sorted is returns the value in but they are not pairs, they are treating each value as its own seperate value.

I have tried to used the built in sort function, but it does not come out the way I want it to show. I am expecting if I type in a = Cards('AH' '4H' 'KH' '2H') and when I run the class function is it will return the pairs in order from greatest to least 'A' 'KH' '4H' '2H'.

I have created the function

```
class Cards:
       def __init__(self, trick)
           self.trick1 = trick

def trick_winner(self):
        R = {'2': 0, '3': 0, '4': 0, '5': 0, '6': 0,
         'J': 4, 'Q': 3, 'K': 5, '7': 10, 'A': 11}
        
        self.trick1 = self.trick1.upper()
        
        a = sorted(self.trick1)
        print(a)
```

and running the funcntion:
c = cards('7H' ' JH' ' KH' ' 2H')
c.trick_winner()

the outcome was:
[' ', ' ', ' ', '2', '7', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'J', 'K']

Answer (score 0):

You should create a class for a single card and implement the order. Look here:

```
R = {"2": 0, "3": 0, "4": 0, "5": 0, "6": 0, "J": 4, "Q": 3, "K": 5, "7": 10, "A": 11}

class Card:
    def __init__(self, color, value):
        self.color = color
        self.value = value

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return R[self.value] < R[other.value]

    # Only for printing purposes, you shouldn't use that in production
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)

c1 = Card("H", "A")
c2 = Card("H", "K")
c3 = Card("H", "7")
c4 = Card("H", "4")
print(sorted([c1, c2, c3, c4], reverse=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

For a bit more structured answer, I created card and cards class which makes sense.

```
#Define R at the beginning of the script so it would be globally accesible
R = {'2': 0, '3': 0, '4': 0, '5': 0, '6': 0,
'J': 4, 'Q': 3, 'K': 5, '7': 10, 'A': 11}

class Card:
    def __init__(self,card):
        self.card = card

    #this function used when checking greater than symbol
    #so that sorted method will work properly
    def __gt__(self,other):
        if(isinstance(other,Card)):
            return R[other.card] > R[self.card]
    #these two are for printing results.
    def __str__(self):
        return self.card

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.card)


class Cards:
    #you can add many card into cards class
    def __init__(self, *cards):
        self.cards = cards

    def trick_winner(self):
        
        a = sorted(self.cards)
        print(a)
```

Here create many card and send them into cards class. Now you can easily manipulate or use them with Cards class

```
c = Cards(Card('A'),Card('4'),Card('K'),Card('2'))
c.trick_winner()
```